# Something Is Interfering With My Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not entirely sure what is going on, but everything was working pretty great and we have a thing called FallingLeavesChristmas.min.js and it's not activating on this page specifically. I thought at first it was the js itself but its not. It works on other pages, just not this one specifically.

```
      <audio id="sound" width="300" height="32" controls="controls" loop autoplay ><source src="http://files.enjin.com/692771/tss.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.enjin.com/692771/FallingLeavesChristmas.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://files.enjin.com/692771/Particles/e-particles.js"></script>
<link href="http://files.enjin.com/972880/Web_Dev/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

   <script src="//use.resrc.it/0.9"></script>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

  <link href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="social">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="http://twitter.com/eternagaming">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://facebook.com/eternagaming">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/eternagaming">Twitch<i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="http://youtube.com/eternagaming">YouTube<i class="fa fa-youtube-play "></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="mailto:info@eternagaming.com">Email Us <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>

          </ul>
      </nav>

   <div id="preloader"> <div id="status">The cat is running to load the site for you, please wait a few seconds while she gathers enough yarn to complete the site.<br></div></div>

<script>
    resrc.ready(function() {
        resrc.run();
    });
</script>

<div id="econtainer">
<div id="ebanner" class="resrc"></div></div>

<div id="sponsorsandpartners">
    <marquee loop="infinite" scrollamount="5" direction="left" scrolldelay="20" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">



        <a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="popup1">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GrsC9KK.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a> 


        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

         <a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="popup2">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZDwwbws.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

<a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="popup3">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcbqiw9.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/skyforge" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3Xp0sva.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

        <a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/codzombies" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dg2OgJP.png" height="100px" title="" alt="" style="border: none;" />
        </a>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

        <a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/starwarsbf" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fwCAEh1.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;


            <a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/thedivision" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TDIO51H.png" title="" alt="" height="100px" style="border: none;" />
        </a>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;



    </marquee>
</div>
<style>
    #sponsorsandpartners {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
border-bottom: solid 1px grey; 
border-top: solid 1px grey; 
 }


#halloween-leavescontainer {
z-index: 9999 !important; }
#econtainer {
height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}


#ebanner {
    background: url(http://puu.sh/lPqmq/a9c01d4418.jpg) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#ebanner:hover {
background: url(http://puu.sh/lPqnZ/173ca118a1.jpg) no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    top: 50px;
}

#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#status {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://puu.sh/lPSYN/92f4fd658a.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
}
.resrc {
    width: 100;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.me {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
   z-index:99999;
}
.me p,
.me h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.me p {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.me span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.social {
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index:999;
}
.social ul {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  transform: translate(-270px, 0);
   z-index:99999;
}
.social ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
   z-index:99999;
}
.social ul li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  transform: translate(110px, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
 z-index:99999;}
.social ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
}
.social ul li:hover i {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
   z-index:99999;
}
.social ul li i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
   z-index:99999;
}
</style>

<div class="ticker-title"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> &nbsp;Announcements</div>
<div class="tickercontainer"><marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="black" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
<div class="mask"><ul id="webticker" class="newsticker" style="display: block; width: 100%; transition-duration: 0s;"><li>    

<h1><font color="#FFFFFF">The new Home Page has been released to the public! Thanks to everyone for their amazing support!</marquee></font></h1>
<span class="tickeroverlay-left">&nbsp;</span><span class="tickeroverlay-right">&nbsp;</span></div></div></ul></li>

                                            <style>
    .ticker-title {
    position: absolute;
padding-left: 10px;
    left: -160px !important;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 11px 11px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tickercontainer {
border-bottom: solid 1px grey;}

.ticker-title {
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #26c3f6, #096aa1);
background-size: 100%;
height: 16px;
margin-left: 45px;}



.ticker-title {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #26c3f6, #096aa1);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #26c3f6, #096aa1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #26c3f6, #096aa1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #26c3f6, #096aa1);
}


.tickercontainer .mask {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    top: 0;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.newsticker {
    -webkit-transition: all 0s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0s linear;
    transition: all 0s linear;
    position: relative;
    font: 700 10px Verdana;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.newsticker li {
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 30px;
}

.tickeroverlay-left {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    height: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    left: -2px;
}

.tickeroverlay-right {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    height: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
}

body {
background-image: url(http://puu.sh/lQ7oF/e4ed948ea5.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; }

#sponsorsandpartners {
background-image: url(http://assets-cloud.enjin.com/themes/1449695092_1285240727_1285127069_base2.png);
</style>

<style>


.v-center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.v-center > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 3vmin;
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn-small {
  padding: .75em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 98%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
@media (min-width: 32em) {

.modal-box { width: 70%; }
}

.modal-box header,
.modal-box .modal-header {
  padding: 1.25em 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.modal-box header h3,
.modal-box header h4,
.modal-box .modal-header h3,
.modal-box .modal-header h4 { margin: 0; }

.modal-box .modal-body { padding: 2em 1.5em; }

.modal-box footer,
.modal-box .modal-footer {
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  text-align: right;
}

.modal-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}

a.close {
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a.close:hover {
  color: #222;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.modal-box .modal-body {
z-index:9999 !important;
position: fixed;
width: 500px;
color: black;}

.modal-box {
position: fixed !important;
z-index: 9999 !important;
width: 550px !important;
top: 150px !important;
height:350px}

.modal-box header h3, .modal-box header h4, .modal-box .modal-header h3, .modal-box .modal-header h4 {
color: black;
font-family: 'Rajdhani';
font-weight: 800;
width: 550px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px; }

.modal-box footer { 
margin-top: 240px;
z-index: 9999; }

ul.newsticker {
bottom: 10px; }

.modal-body img {
width: 102%;
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;}

audio {
width: 45px;
}

#sound {
top: 100px !important;
position: fixed !important;
z-index: 99 !important;
left: 2px;
display: block; }

.modal-body img {
width: 102%;
height: 210px;
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;}

.btn1 {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>


<script>
$(function(){

var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

    $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    //$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
        var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
        $('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
    });  


$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
    $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".modal-overlay").remove();
    });

});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".modal-box").css({
        top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
        left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
    });
});

$(window).resize();

});
</script>



<div id="popup1" class="modal-box">
<a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>BLACK DESERT</h3><div class="modal-body">
<img src="http://puu.sh/kTJRC/cb81924404.png">
         <center><a href="/blackdesert"<button class="btn1">APPLY</button></a><a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/forums/m/22050109/viewforum/6434643"><button class="btn1">FORUMS</button></a><a href="/blackdesertapp"><button class="btn1">MORE INFO</button></a></center>
</div></div>

<div id="popup2" class="modal-box">
  <header> <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>BLADE AND SOUL</h3>
  </header>
    <div class="modal-body"><img src="http://puu.sh/k4NhN/8737ff4470.png">
         <center><a href="/bns"<button class="btn1">APPLY</button></a><a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/forums/m/22050109/viewforum/6264833"><button class="btn1">FORUMS</button></a><a href="/bnsmemberapply"><button class="btn1">MORE INFO</button></a></center>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup3" class="modal-box">
  <header> <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>BLADE AND SOUL</h3>
  </header>
    <div class="modal-body"><img src="http://puu.sh/kwfs5/aef1615929.png">
         <center><a href="/Dragomon"<button class="btn1">APPLY</button></a><a href="http://www.eternagaming.com/forums/m/22050109/viewforum/6378259"><button class="btn1">FORUMS</button></a><a href="/dragomonmemberapp"><button class="btn1">MORE INFO</button></a><center>

  </div>
</div>
```

The website this is on is: http://www.eternagaming.com/home2clone

Comment: is jquery included? I see your other .js files, but not JQ

Comment: You have an error in e-particles.js, which is loading before your christmas-js. The error is depending on jQuery, $ is not defined.

Comment: Jquery is already implemented by default.

Comment: I just removed e-particles entirely just to test it out and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move or add `jquery.js` before any file that requires jquery. Looks like `e-particles.js` is throwing the error. Trying moving it before that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I simply removed the entire thing and created a snow effect using CSS instead.